My webpage has an element where i am unable to pass text getting element not interactable
Html markup looks like this:
<form id="a_abc_abcd15:form" name="a_abc_abcd15:form xxxxxxx>

And this is the text box markup:
<input id="a_abc_abcd05:userPassword" type="text" name="a_abc_abcd05:userPassword" xxxxxx>

The issue is whatever selector I tried,  I get element not interactable.
Here's my complete code:
void Login() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td/input")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("a_abc_abcd05:userPassword")).sendKeys("xxxxxxx");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td/input")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

but still the same issue occurs - please help. Thanks in advance

/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td/input locators like this are brittle in nature. one day it works and other day it wouldn't. So I'd suggest you to use more relative locators.

/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td/input locators like this are brittle in nature. one day it works and other day it wouldn't. So I'd suggest you to use more relative locators.
to resolve ElementNotInteractableException in Java, you can try approach:

Make sure the browser is launched in full screen using :
driver.manage().window().maximize();


Use Actions class:   
Actions actionProvider = new Actions(driver);    
actionProvider.moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='a_abc_abcd05:userPassword']")))).sendKeys("some text").build().perform();     


Use JavascriptExecutor :
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='a_abc_abcd05:userPassword']")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].sendKeys("some text");", element);



you can check and verify xpath in browser console if that has unique or not.

hi. one more question like the id is dynamically changing so how to handle it

@Mallik : Please raise the new ticket for new requirements thanks.
